# Typescript annotations

Tags: typescript, annotations, marionette, decorator

I am writing project on MarionetteJS using TS and I want to use annotations to register routes.
For example:

```
@Controller
class SomeController {

  @RouteMapping("some route")
  public SomeMethod() {
     //code
  }
}
```

Is there opportunity to call method annotations when I create class instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there isn't.

Check out this article [Decorators & metadata reflection in TypeScript](http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-reflection-javascript-typescript). It shows how decorators are transformed into pure javascript and therefore when they are called.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [typescript-rest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-rest)

It allows to configure services with annotation and generates Swagger file if needed

Comment: Nice but this library is for node.js =)